# "To develop" vs. "On developing"

Tags: grammar

I am writing a school project report and I came across the following. What is the difference between the two? Which is more preferred if there is no difference in meaning?

> Our focus is *on developing* a model that is both easy and extendable...
>
> Our focus is *to develop* a model that is both easy and extendable...

Comment: I would consider to say "Our focus is developing ...".

Answer (score 2):

They're both very similar, but I see two key differences in the focus of the sentence:

To say your focus is *on developing*, is use the verb develop as more of an ongoing process; there's more focus in the *process* of developing, rather than the end goal of developing.

To say your focus is *to develop*, is more goal oriented; there's more emphasis on the verb develop as something that needs to be finished.

They'll both serve you well in either situation, but you may have more success getting your point across if you take that into account.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Zolani13 that if you say your focus is on developing a model that you're emphasizing the development process.

I think the first sentence is a more common construction with the word *focus*. We are used to hearing the preposition "on" with the word "focus" -- *We focus on things.* If you want to use the second sentence, you might want to reword it slightly to: Our *aim* is to develop a model that is both easy and extendable...

You might be interested in this NGram (a graph comparing the two phrases from 1950 to 2008, in "lots of" English language books):

[image: NGram of focus is on developing vs focus is to develop]

Answer (score 0):

From the bird's eye view of work-flow analysis, there are three stages:

- Subject definition
- Goal definition
- Execution.

As further elaboration ...

1. Subject definition:
   The talks and discussions are **on** developing a more efficient and effective model.
   The focus is **on** developing a more efficient and effective model.
   The subject is "developing a more efficient and effective model".
2. Goal definition:
   The strategy and intention is **to** develop a more efficient and effective model.
   The focus is **to** develop a more efficient and effective model.
   The goal is "developing a more efficient and effective model".
3. Execution:
   Process **for** developing a more efficient and effective model have started.
   The focus is "developing a more efficient and effective model".
   The result **of** "developing a more efficient and effective model" will be increased profits.